# Doble instancia de una misma librería dentro de controlador en Codeigniter3

Tags: php, codeigniter, libreria

necesito instanciar desde un controlador de Condeigniter 3 una misma librería pero pasando parámetros distintos. Ejemplo

```
$this->load->library('milibreria', $parametro1);
```

en otro lugar del controlador necesito cargar la libreria pero con otro parámetro

```
$this->load->library('milibreria', $parametro2);
```

No logro cómo hacer esto, espero su ayuda.

Comment: Sé POO en PHP, sólo quería una solución dentro del entorno de CI, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la misma librería pero asignándola a otro nombre de objeto dentro de codeigniter:

```
$this->load->library('calendar', $opts, 'my_calendar');
$this->load->library('calendar', $opts, 'other_calendar');

// Calendar class is now accessed using:
$this->my_calendar->method();
$this->other_calendar->method();
```

Documentación: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/loader.html#CI_Loader

Comment: Muchas gracias, era esto lo que estaba buscando, me funcionó perfecto.